# I import a KMZ into QGIS but I would like to display the path name next to path in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I have a KMZ/KML file I import into QGIS. The file in Google Earth has track names but after importing to QGIS, only the tracks/paths are visible. How do I get the individual path names (which I can view in the attributes table) to view on the main window alongside the respective path/track?

Comment: A simple search about labeling will give you your answer.

Answer (score 1):

One possible option would be to change the symbology of a chosen layer which contains multiple tracks into Categorized->Column (Name) or as suggested before add labels
[image]

[image]